# How to call var from within an other function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the exif orientation variable in my function, but I can grab it to the other function... How could I get it please (var orientat)?

```
$(function() {
        $('#takePictureField').change(function(e) {
            $("#canvas_captimg").show();
            $( "#imgcaptmobile" ).empty();
            $( "#imgcaptmobile" ).hide();

            var file = e.target.files[0],
                imageType = /image.*/;

            if (!file.type.match(imageType))
                return;
                    var fr = new FileReader();
                    fr.onload = function() {
                 var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(this.result));
                   // console.log(exif.Orientation);
                    var orientat = exif.Orientation;
                };
                fr.readAsBinaryString(file);

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = fileOnload;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

        function fileOnload(e) {
            var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
            var canvas = $('#canvas_captimg')[0];
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            $img.load(function() {
                var MAX_WIDTH = 487;
                  var MAX_HEIGHT = 1800;
                  var width = this.width;
                  var height = this.height;

                  var moit_width_2 = 0;
                  var moit_height_2 = 0;
console.log(orientat);
                  if (orientat > 1) {
                    if (orientat == 3 || orientat == 4) {
                        var rotation = 180;
                    }
                    if (orientat == 6 || orientat == 5) {
                        var rotation = 90;
                    }
                    if (orientat == 8 || orientat == 7) {
                        var rotation = 270;
                    }
                    var moit_width = width / 2;
                      var moit_height = height / 2;
                      var moit_width_2 = 0 - moit_width;
                      var moit_height_2 = 0 - moit_height;

                      context.translate(moit_width, moit_height);
                            context.rotate(rotation * Math.PI/180);
                  }

                  if (width > height) {
                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                      height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                      width = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                  } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                      width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                      height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                  }

                context.drawImage(this, moit_width_2, moit_height_2, width, height);
                 $( "#imgcaptmobile" ).append( '<img id="imagecaptmobile" src="' + canvas.toDataURL("image/png") + '" style="display:hidden">');
            });
        }
        });
```

Comment: why not make it global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the answer at - [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) about how variable scope works within javascript to gain some understanding of what you are requesting.

To answer your question, make the variable global or pass it as a parameter to the function.

To make it global try the following:

add the following line at the start.

```
var orientat;
```

update the assignment to

```
orientat = exif.Orientation;
```

Comment: thats what i mentioned in the comment :)

Comment: Yes, in fact I've done it before but I updated the variable with "var orient = ...." now I put "orient = " and it works, thanks!